# C# get/set inheritance?

Tags: c#, get, set

I am not sure this is syntactically possible.  If I have duplicate logic that would go in a getter/setter.  Is there a way for a variable to inherit that pattern instead of re-typing the code.

```
    private int basicVar;
public int BasicVar
    {
    get { return basicVar; }
    set
    {
        if (IsServer)
        {
            basicVar  = value;
            Debug.Log("The variable name is: " + nameof(BasicVar)); 
            //Other code
        }
    }
    }

private int turn
public int Turn
{
    //Inherits from basicVar
}
```

I am not sure if such a thing is possible, I was just curious.
(If it is, how could I template the private variable?)
I could do this by making it its own class, but I would prefer to keep it a primitive.

Comment: You cannot and should not do this. Side effects are discouraged in getters and setters. If you have reusable behavior, encapsulate it in a method.

Comment: Fair enough.  The method would then go in a class and not the namespace of the variable right?  Could you clarify what you mean by side effects.  I have not heard that term before?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, when needing to build reusable behavior, the preferred approach is to encapsulate the behavior in functions that can be called instead of the getter/setter of the property itself. This allows you to clearly define your expected behavior and allows you to easily compose logic by calling other methods.

```
public class Test
{
    public bool IsServer { get; set;  }
    public int BasicVar { get; set }
    public int Turn { get; set; }
    
    public void UpdateBasicVar(int updatedValue)
    {
        if (IsServer)
        {
            BasicVar  = updatedValue;
            Debug.Log("The variable name is: " + nameof(BasicVar)); 
            //Other code
        }
    }
    
    public void UpdateTurnAndBasicVar(int updatedValue)
    {
        Turn = updatedValue;
        Debug.Log("The variable name is: " + nameof(Turn)); 
        
        UpdateBasicVar(updatedValue);
    }
}
```

This also helps prevent side effects in your code.  Typically, when using properties, C# developers expect that interacting with that property ONLY affects that property. It is not expected that updating one property would also update another.

Consider the following example:

```
public class SideEffects
{
    private int basicVar;
    public int BasicVar
    {
        get { return basicVar; }
        set 
        {
            if (IsServer)
            {
                basicVar  = value;
                Debug.Log("The variable name is: " + nameof(BasicVar)); 
                //Other code
            }
        }
    }
    
    private int turn;
    public int Turn
    {
        get { return turn; }
        set
        {
            turn = value;
            BasicVar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

while this is essentially functionally equivalent to the previous method-based example, it is no longer self-documenting.  There is no way to determine from the public contract of the class that updating Turn will also update BasicVar, which is considered a side effect.